# Ajax country sate city selection for editing an information

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I a trying to edit and information using an API from

http://iamrohit.in/lab/php_ajax_country_state_city_dropdown/api.php

This api helps me to load all the countries at first and on changing them populates corresponding states and cities. This works fine when I am tryin to add new information and it is supposed to be selected with interaction.

But if I want to edit that information , using this code

```
$('.countries').change().val(editCn);
   $('.states').change().val(editSt);
   $('.cities').change().val(editCt);
```

the country gets selected but states and city does not. It gets populated only when I  change the country once again and I have to select it again.

Now for more information if you want to see the code for api than ,

```
function ajaxCall() {
        this.send = function(data, url, method, success, type) {
          type = type||'json';
          var successRes = function(data) {
              success(data);
          }
          var errorRes = function(e) {
              //alert("Error found \nError Code: "+e.status+" \nError Message: "+e.statusText);
              //$('#loader').modal('hide');
          }
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: method,
                data: data,
                success: successRes,
                error: errorRes,
                dataType: type,
                timeout: 60000
            });

          }

        }

function locationInfo() {
    var rootUrl = "http://iamrohit.in/lab/php_ajax_country_state_city_dropdown/api.php";
    var call = new ajaxCall();
    this.getCities = function(id) {
        $(".cities option:gt(0)").remove();
        var url = rootUrl+'?type=getCities&stateId=' + id;
        var method = "post";
        var data = {};
        $('.cities').find("option:eq(0)").html("Please wait..");
        call.send(data, url, method, function(data) {
            $('.cities').find("option:eq(0)").html("Select City");
            if(data.tp == 1){
                $.each(data['result'], function(key, val) {
                    var option = $('<option />');
                    option.attr('value', val).text(val);
                     option.attr('cityid', key);
                    $('.cities').append(option);
                });
                $(".cities").prop("disabled",false);
            }
            else{
                 alert(data.msg);
            }
        });
    };
    this.getStates = function(id) {
        $(".states option:gt(0)").remove();
        $(".cities option:gt(0)").remove();
        var url = rootUrl+'?type=getStates&countryId=' + id;
        var method = "post";
        var data = {};
        $('.states').find("option:eq(0)").html("Please wait..");
        call.send(data, url, method, function(data) {
            $('.states').find("option:eq(0)").html("Select State");
            if(data.tp == 1){
                $.each(data['result'], function(key, val) {
                    var option = $('<option />');
                        option.attr('value', val).text(val);
                        option.attr('stateid', key);
                    $('.states').append(option);
                });
                $(".states").prop("disabled",false);
            }
            else{
                alert(data.msg);
            }
        });
    };

    this.getCountries = function() {
        var url = rootUrl+'?type=getCountries';
        var method = "post";
        var data = {};
        $('.countries').find("option:eq(1)").html("Please wait..");
        call.send(data, url, method, function(data) {
            $('.countries').find("option:eq(0)").html("Select Country");
            console.log(data);
            if(data.tp == 1){
                $.each(data['result'], function(key, val) {
                    var option = $('<option />');
                    option.attr('value', val).text(val);
                     option.attr('countryid', key);
                    $('.countries').append(option);
                });
                $(".countries").prop("disabled",false);
            }
            else{
                alert(data.msg);
            }
        });
    };

}

$(function() {
var loc = new locationInfo();
loc.getCountries();
 $(".countries").on("change", function(ev) {
        var countryId = $("option:selected", this).attr('countryid');
        if(countryId != ''){
        loc.getStates(countryId);
        }
        else{
            $(".states option:gt(0)").remove();
        }
    });
 $(".states").on("change", function(ev) {
        var stateId = $("option:selected", this).attr('stateid');
        if(stateId != ''){
        loc.getCities(stateId);
        }
        else{
            $(".cities option:gt(0)").remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Any answer to this question will help me alot. I have tried many ways But did not worked.

Comment: you have to call city and state method on onload by giving default id.

Comment: can you please read the question again? orelse..can you elaborate your answer?

Comment: your loc.getStates(countryId) function is called on change of country with id,same way you have to call this function statically in case of edit information with id.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a minor mistake.Suppose I have this

```
<select onchange="alert(this.value)">
  <option value="a">1</option>
  <option value="b">2</option>
  <option value="c">3</option>
</select>
```

Now if you run `$('select').change().val("b");` it would `alert("a")` this is because value is changed only after change event gets processed since you've assigned ajax code to run on change event that will use old value resulting in no visible change in selectbox contents

Invoking change later would fix it

```
$('.countries').val(editCn).change();
$('.states').val(editSt).change();
$('.cities').val(editCt).change();
```